# Any message sent to id compiling, basis?

Tags: objective-c, methods

In Xcode, if I write -

```
id a;
```

As I start writing message to a, [a ..., Xcode gives a long list of autocomplete suggestions. On what basis these suggestions are coming (apparently all possible method names)?

I can compile any method call, like

```
[a viewDidLoad];
```

I know id can take any message.
But

```
[a asdfgh]; //asdfgh random string
```

doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

> On what basis these suggestions are coming (apparently all possible method names)?

These suggestions are somewhat intelligent: as far as I can tell, they count in the class and the adopted protocols of an object. Since `id` is generic, and as such, any existent message can potentially be sent to it (which it may or may not respond to), Xcode suggests whatever it finds in any class or protocol.

> but [a asdfgh]; doesn't compile

Because the compiler **does provide** some level of protection. If a selector is not declared anywhere at all, it assumes that selector to be nonexistent, thus it's impossible to send it to any object, hence it complains.

Answer (score 1):

Here you see what is `id`

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

It is not `void *` at all, but rather a pointer to a `struct` that contains a single member, pointing at the class definition. Therefore it can take form of any data type at runtime. **Dynamically Typed**.

At compile time it checks for correct method name, if it exists?

`[a asdfgh];` produces error as there is not method/selector with name `asdfgh`.

While `[a viewDidLoad];` compiles fine, however at runtime it may crash!

Comment: "id is just like void *" - Sorry, but this is one of the worst/most misleading kind of explanation about what `id` is.

Comment: @H2CO3: And why i love SO, is here, teaches me a lot everyday.